# Float left not working in one particular page

Tags: css, wordpress

This is a website which I am maintaining with wordpress. I am having a peculiar problem where there is this one page page where the side bar is not floating to left. Completely annoyed with my page's behaviour. Can someone help me what is missing.
the page is here: http://myingage.com/kochadaiiyaan/ 
The Primary and Secondary div are left float in other pages but not this one.

Comment: You have a clear being applied to your secondary div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not floating because of this style:

```
.template-front-page .widget-area
{
 clear: both;
}
```

Removing that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to switch primary div with secondary, and looks like it works how you would expect.

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary"> ... </div>
<div id="primary" class="site-content"> ... </div>
```